# Add Docker Run command options in AWS Dockerrun.aws.json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my `docker-compose.yml` file I can do the following:

```
splash:
  image: scrapinghub/splash
  command: --max-timeout 300
  ports:
    - "8050:8050"
```

As you can see, I just pass in the additional options that I want to add to the docker run command that is executed in the image.

When I try to apply this to my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file that is deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, I get error when I write the following:

```
{
    "name": "splash",
    "image": "scrapinghub/splash", 
    ...
    "command": [
        "--max-timeout 300"
    ]
},
```

So question is, how do I add the `--max-timeout` parameter to the default command that my Docker Image is executing with my AWS deployment?

Answer (score -1):

You cant customize how AWS start a container by playing with DOCKER RUN options. You have to use .ebextensions .
If you want to increase timeout, create a file in .ebextensions sub directory of your ZIP package (it should already contains the Dockerrun.aws.json file) :

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elb:policies
    option_name: ConnectionSettingIdleTimeout
    value: 300
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
    option_name: Timeout
    value: 300
  - namespace: aws:elbv2:loadbalancer
    option_name: IdleTimeout
    value: 300
```